# rosrun error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run

**rosrun package python scripts**

and get some errors below:

```
(cv-py3) hoang@hoang-Nitro-AN515-51:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun testpy test.py 
Parsing cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-3c.cfg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/test.py", line 41, in <module>
    tfnet = TFNet(options)
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/darkflow/net/build.py", line 58, in __init__
    darknet = Darknet(FLAGS)
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/darkflow/dark/darknet.py", line 17, in __init__
    src_parsed = self.parse_cfg(self.src_cfg, FLAGS)
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/darkflow/dark/darknet.py", line 68, in parse_cfg
    for i, info in enumerate(cfg_layers):
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/darkflow/utils/process.py", line 66, in cfg_yielder
    layers, meta = parser(model); yield meta;
  File "/home/hoang/catkin_ws/src/testpy/src/darkflow/utils/process.py", line 17, in parser
    with open(model, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-3c.cfg'
```

Note: those **errors stop** when I **run rosrun in the script's folder**. But, I wanna **add a node in package launch file** to use roslaunch for python scripts.

What I need to do? Thanks in advance!

I followed these steps:

> $ cd ~

> $ mkdir catkin_ws/src -p

> $ cd catkin_ws

> $ catkin_make

> $ cd src

> $ catkin_create_pkg testpy rospy

this step I copy all scripts to package/src folder

> $ cd ~/catkin_ws

> $ catkin_make

> $ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

> $ roscore

> $ chmod +x test.py   (added #!/usr/bin/env python)

> $ rosrun testpy test.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312389/rosrun-error-filenotfounderror:-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [MCVB](https://answers.ros.org/users/39399/mcvb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-10**:
Please copy-paste the errors *directly* into your question. Do not use screenshots. It's all text.

**Comment by [MCVB](https://answers.ros.org/users/39399/mcvb/) on 2019-01-10**:
Ok, It was edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-3c.cfg'
> ```

ROS changes the *current working directory* for nodes when using `rosrun` and `roslaunch`. You cannot use relative filenames then. Change it to an absolute path and it should work.

See #q33890 for a very old -- but still correct -- explanation of this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1